# Symfony2 - PHP fatal error Class not found

Tags: composer-php, bundle, symfony-2.7

I have a weird behaviour with my symfony2 project. A few days ago, I've tried to add a custom form listener which failed because symfony didn't find the namespace. <- Just for your information

I didn't work on this error, because I had some other things to do. Now, I wanted to add an VAT-Validator to my signup form and I was using

```
composer require ddeboer/vatin-bundle
```

to add this bundle to my project. It was working great in my dev-enviroment. Then, when I wanted to update my project on my staging-webserver with git and while clearing the cache with

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

I get this message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Ddeboer\VatinBundle\DdeboerVatinBundle' not found in ../app/AppKernel.php on line 24
```

I have tried it with other bundles, too. But its the same error with every "new" bundle. Since, I have experienced the namespace problem just a few days before, I guess there is a problem with autoloading or something.

Already, tried various solution I have found on google and stackoverflow.
In the documentation, there is a hint:

> If you get a "class not found" error during this step, you may need to run `export SYMFONY_ENV=prod` before running this command so that the post-install-cmd scripts run in the prod environment.

I am using windows and this command is not working. Also, on my ubuntu server I can use this command, but there seems to be no effect.

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "Admin/myproject",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/",
        "SymfonyStandard": "app/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^3.2",
    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~1.0",
    "cocur/slugify": "^2.0",
    "ddeboer/vatin-bundle": "^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "~2.2"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
```

}